# Using external git repo in SVN

Tags: git, svn

Is it possible to use external git repo inside SVN? The thing is the designers of some third party source code we are using moved from SVN to git. And we were using their code as external svn. So, it's not very clear how to make something similar with git repository.

Comment: If it’s third-party code, shouldn’t you keep it separated from your code anyway?

Comment: Well, may be it's uncommon, but we keep this code in our folder.

Answer (score 0):

If the third party can put their source code on github (even as a private repository), you could use your svn client against the github repository, see https://github.com/blog/966-improved-subversion-client-support

However @poke is correct, you're normally better off keeping third party source code out of your codebase.